# Forecasting by ID and Product in R

Tags: r, product, forecasting

I need the data from the table below so I can forecast by ID and ProductCode.  I am stumped on how to code R so I can forecast by ID and ProductCode.  I am looking into zoo to help me do this, but I am stumped.

```
DATE    ID  ProdCode    Rev
08/01/2012   1-100FDK    B51    0.22
09/01/2012   1-100FDK    B51    10.17
10/01/2012   1-100FDK    B51    39.73
11/01/2012   1-100FDK    B51    78.77
12/01/2012   1-100FDK    B51    167.66
08/01/2012   1-100FDK    B53    387.82
09/01/2012   1-100FDK    B53    321.58
10/01/2012   1-100FDK    B53    261.9
11/01/2012   1-100FDK    B53    259.84
12/01/2012   1-100FDK    B53    269.84
08/01/2012   1-200FFK    A54    194.42
09/01/2012   1-200FFK    A54    225.1
10/01/2012   1-200FFK    A54    269.42
11/01/2012   1-200FFK    A54    321.14
12/01/2012   1-200FFK    A54    429.11
```

Thanks,

Jeff

Comment: The questions on StackOverflow deal with specific programming problems. Right now you cannot produce a simple example, so your question if not a good fit for SO. I would recommend you try more tutorials, read more, maybe find a colleague who can help you out.

Answer (score 2):

I would begin by visualizing my data to get some intuitions , detect patterns and choose the best model. R is really great for this. Here I am using `ggplot2` but you can do the same thing using `lattice`. For example :

```
dat$DATE <- as.Date(dat$DATE,format='%d/%m/%Y')
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat,aes(x=DATE,y=Rev,group=ProdCode,color=ProdCode)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_grid(~ID) +
  geom_smooth(method='lm')
```

[image]

Here dat are :

```
dat <- read.table(text='DATE    ID  ProdCode    Rev
08/01/2012   1-100FDK    B51    0.22
09/01/2012   1-100FDK    B51    10.17
10/01/2012   1-100FDK    B51    39.73
11/01/2012   1-100FDK    B51    78.77
12/01/2012   1-100FDK    B51    167.66
08/01/2012   1-100FDK    B53    387.82
09/01/2012   1-100FDK    B53    321.58
10/01/2012   1-100FDK    B53    261.9
11/01/2012   1-100FDK    B53    259.84
12/01/2012   1-100FDK    B53    269.84
08/01/2012   1-200FFK    A54    194.42
09/01/2012   1-200FFK    A54    225.1
10/01/2012   1-200FFK    A54    269.42
11/01/2012   1-200FFK    A54    321.14
12/01/2012   1-200FFK    A54    429.11',
         header=TRUE)
```

Comment: I applaud your effort (+1), but the question of the OP is so broad an entire time series analysis and forecasting book would be needed to answer the question.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra yes you are right. I totally agree with you. My aim is to attract people to use R and I think that a nice plot can persuade the OP to do more effort next time.

Comment: I voted to close as being too broad

Comment: @PaulHiemstra mee too.